# Why isnt Dijkstra's algorithm's (for shortest path) time complexity the same as DFS?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, dijkstra

Can't Dijkstra's algorithm be implemented using a DFS that keeps track of the length of the current path traveled and every time it arrives in an unvisited node it updates the length of the shortest path to that node, and if the node arrived at is already visited, update the length if the current length is smaller than the length in the node?

Which is just DFS, meaning the run time should be linear ( O(|V| + |E|) ).

Comment: Well, no, because then it is no longer Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Doesnt it achieve the same thing?

Comment: How do you know, it is "shortest" (when you haven't (re-)sorted the nodes... which dijksra does with extra `O(log(|V|))` time complexity) ..?

Comment: Not really, if you "update the length if the current length is smaller than the length in the node" there could be other nodes that need update as well when they were reached from the updated node.

Comment: If I replace DFS with BFS, Im guessing it also has some problem, do you know which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this graph as example, where the search should start in *a*, and the target node is *c*:

[image]

### DFS

Assuming children of a node are traversed in their lexical order, a DFS will visit the nodes in the order a, b, c, d, e

It will find these distances:

```
 a: 0
 b: 5
 c: 13
 d: 8
```

Then from *d* it will see *c* again, and update it to 12

Next is:

```
 e: 1
```

From *e* it will see *b* again, and update it to 3. But then a DFS falls short of also seeing the impact this change has on nodes *c* and *d*.

### Dijkstra's

Dijkstra's algorithm, on the other hand, will visit nodes in this order:

```
 a: 0
 e: 1
 b: 3
```

Then it will take the edge with weight 5, but see that *b* was already visited, and ignore it. Then:

```
 d: 6
 c: 10
```

... and the target was found with the correct distance.

### BFS

Just to answer to your comment below: BFS will also not find the correct path, because BFS does not take the (total) weights into consideration; it just minimises the number of edges on a path.

BFS will visit the nodes like this:

```
a: 0

b: 5
e: 1

c: 13
```

... and it will stop there. If you would not stop, but continue (with potential overwriting), then the process continues:

```
d: 8
```

Then it sees *b* from *e*, and updates:

```
b: 3
```

However, as *b* was already visited, BFS will not see the impact this change has on *c* and *d*.

It also sees *c* from *d* and updates *c* to 12. Then there is nothing more to do for BFS, and clearly the result is wrong.

Comment: If I replace DFS with BFS im guessing it would still have some problem, do you know which?

Comment: BFS will not take the weights into consideration, so you would extend your search to 2 steps away from the start, 3 steps away, 4 steps away, ...etc, while Dijkstra would extend paths based on total weight, so some paths might have more edges than other concurrent ones. Obviously BFS risks to get to the target via a path with fewer edges, but with larger weight. In fact, the example I gave in my answer also demonstrates this. BFS will find *c* in 2 steps and stop.

Comment: I added a section on BFS to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you arrive at a visited node, called A, assume that the length of current path is shorter than the length in A, so you update length to A. But what about those nodes that connect with A? You need to update them too, but you can't, because A is already visited.

In short, the run time is linear, but the algorithm is incorrect.